# Update a git commit

Tags: git

I want to understand the best approach of revising a git commits I made earlier.

Lets say I have a history of commits like :

```
FeatureA --> FixB --> FixC --> FeatureD --> HEAD
```

Assume I realize that FixB did not completely fixed the problem it should and want to update it.

I would prefer not adding a new commit to the history with a silly name like "`FixBFixed`" but update the original `FixB` commit.

- Does this work? How?
- Or shall I revert `FixB` and commit again?
- What is the best practice to keep commit history clean ?

Comment: Can you explicitly say which elements are commits / branches in your representation? (FeatureA, FixB, ...)

Comment: You will have to rewrite history to do that. Are you sure this is what you want to do? Anyone else also using this repository will have to do some work on their end or you'll end up with a worse situation than you have now.

Comment: @RomainValeri Assume this is a commit history of a single branch, so all are commits

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I see your concern which is fully valid. However, this repository is only used by me for record keeping. So no need to worry about others' effort

Comment: OK. Then one way would be to 1) Check out `FixB`, 2) Create a new branch, 3) Amend your commit with the required changes, 4) Check out "HEAD" (that is, the original branch you were on), 5) rebase this branch on top of the one you created in 2).

Comment: A different method would be interactive rebase. First, create a new commit (at the end) that fixes what is wrong in FixB (and **only** that). Then do an interactive rebase, and move the line with the new fix just under FixB and specify to squash it into the previous commit. This should combine the FixB + its fix into one commit and then rebase the rest on top of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go back and change the commit "FixB" you are essentially **rewriting history**, which is usually not recommended (especially if you already pushed to the remote repo, as this will lead to trouble for anyone who already has your changes).

If you are working on a branch, **and you haven't yet pushed your changes**, you could squash your commits on the branch (essentially combining all of them into one commit. In which case, it won't matter when you FixFixB, because that order will be lost in the one big commit.

I use interactive rebase to clean up my commits, as follows:

- `git rebase -i <commit hash>` to do an interactive rebase from the
  given commit hash.This will open a list of commits with their hashes.
- Replace pick (keep) with squash if you want to squash a commit into
  the previous commit in the list.
- After saving the list, update the commit messages as needed.

Alternatively, tools like GitHub and GitLab offer the option to "squash on merge" when merging a feature branch. This will squash all commits in a branch into one commit on master. Your tooling might offer other options / you may prefer to squash differently.

Also, I am curious what "keeping commit history" clean means to you? An argument could be made that having a commit "FixFixB" on top of the other commits would be more honest (it reflects the correct order of commits) and provides better information as you could add information to your "FixFixB" commit message of the additional fix for FixB, like what you missed the first time and why. That might help you or other developers with similar features in the future.

Finally, how you deal with these things vary per team / project. I work on open source projects and work projects where we squash commits when merging a feature branch to master, but have also worked on teams where we didn't.

Comment: "keeping commit history clean" means that if FixB is large enough but has a simple error - like a typo or other thing that can be medicated in a few lines -then updating that commit is still better (in certain cases) than having FixFixB which is ugly. Once again, I am referring to a situation where no other team members are working on the code.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd still argue it would be more honest to add another commit on top, fixing those issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to change history, which in many cases is not recommended, but in others I think is perfectly reasonable, proceed like this:

- Use interactive rebase with `git rebase -i <FeatureA>` where `<FeatureA>` is a commit hash or branch name.
- In the editor change `pick` to `e` or `edit` in the line of the `FixB` commit.
- Save and exit the editor, your working tree is now in the state of the FixB commit.
- Make the FixFixB changes in the files necessary.
- Use `git add` and `git commit` as you normally would to make your new `FixB` commit.
- Run `git rebase --continue` to finish rebasing.
- Your history is now rewritten with new commits, every commit's hash will change starting from the one you changed, but their contents will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rebase has an "autosquash" feature for fixups like this, see its docs:

> ```
>   --autosquash, --no-autosquash
>
>       When the commit log message begins with "squash! ..." (or "fixup!
>        ..."), and there is already a commit in the todo list that matches
>        the same ..., automatically modify the todo list of rebase -i so
>        that the commit marked for squashing comes right after the commit
>        to be modified, and change the action of the moved commit from pick
>        to squash (or fixup). A commit matches the ...  if the commit
>        subject matches, or if the ...  refers to the commit’s hash. As a
>        fall-back, partial matches of the commit subject work, too. The
>        recommended way to create fixup/squash commits is by using the
>        --fixup/--squash options of git-commit(1).
>
>       If the --autosquash option is enabled by default using the
>        configuration variable rebase.autoSquash, this option can be used
>        to override and disable this setting.
> ```

Make your fix with commit message 'fixup! FixB' and do `git rebase -i --autosquash FixB~`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use any tools for manage git like gitkraken :)